# How to map python2.7 and python 3 to both VIM

Tags: ubuntu, vim

In linux I have configured

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

to map python2.7 to my vim

How can I have both Python2.7 and python3 run on new Ubuntu18LTS and how should I configure the python call for python3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated `python2.7` and `python3` commands on Ubuntu; you can use those to choose the correct version of the interpreter.

If you don't want to have a second mapping (e.g. `<S-F9>`) for Python 3, you need a way to detect the correct Python interpreter. Depending on your scripts, this could be done via the *shebang* line:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' . (getline(1) =~ 'python3' ? '3' : '2.7') shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```